# Download selected rows

Tags: datatables

I am trying to download selected rows in CSV format. The code below works if I have no pagination. It returns only selected rows of a particular page. I want all selected rows (irrespective of page)

```
buttons: [
  { extend :'csv',
    exportOptions : {
     columns: ':visible:not(.not-exported)',
     rows: '.selected'
  }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Looks like you are inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159107/export-selected-rows-with-buttons-collection-not-working-in-datatables - are you in fact using the select plugin?

Comment: Are you using local data or server side processing?

Comment: server side processing